# Unable to add map control to mapbox Nuxt3/Vue3 to zoom

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've created a new Nuxt3 app and I'm playing around with Mapbox.

I got the map to render in my `Map.vue` component I created, but I'm unable to add controls to it and other options. I just can't get the controls to show.

Here's my component code. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
<template>
  <div id="map" class="h-full"></div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { onMounted, defineProps } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
  import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';

  const props = defineProps({
    mapCoords: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  })

  onMounted(() => {
    createMap();
  })

  function createMap() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      center: props.mapCoords,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      zoom: 12
    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
  }
</script>
<style>
@import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css';
</style>
```

I'm also getting this type `unknown` warning in my IDE for the center option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already solved the problem, but maybe someone else has similar problem : the type of mapCoords property needs to be changed from Array to [number, number].

```
  const props = defineProps({
    mapCoords: {
      type: [number, number],
      default: () => [0, 0]
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load CSS file from this buttons

Try this in your code:

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
```